# How to find limit of integration given value of integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Consider $f$ a real integrable function, usually we want to evaluate the integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ for some $a<b$ given. Now, suppose we know $a$ but we don't know $b$, further, we know the value of this integral, let $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lambda$. My question is, in what conditions we can find $b$ given $\lambda$, and how (including numerical methods)?

I'm interested in cases for which $f$ does not have a known primitive.

Comment: because function can fluctuate between positive and negative, it's not possible

Comment: well, let us say that it may be not unique. In such case I would ask to find the closest value to a (always b>a).

Comment: If you want to read more about this: the function you seek is called the [*inverse function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function), i.e. if $F(b) = \int_a^b f(x){\rm d}x$ then you want to find the function $G(\cdot)$ such that $G(F(b)) = b$. There is no general method to solve for the inverse analytically and very few elementary functions will have inverse functions that are elementary functions.

Answer (score 3):

You assume very little, so your options are very limited. Since $f$ is integrable, the function $F : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$$ is continuous. This enables the use of the intermediate value theorem. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be found such that $$F(x_1) < \lambda < F(x_2),$$ then there exists at least one $b$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $$F(b) = \lambda.$$ With no additional information about $f$, random sampling seems the only option when searching for $x_1$ and $x_2$. Without continuity of $f$ we loose all quadrature methods for approximating $F$ as they depend on our ability to compute specific *function* values. Continuity of $f$ would allows us to approximate $F$ on a set of discrete points and this can facilitate the search for $x_1$ and $x_2$. Interpolating $F$ with say a spline could potentially accelerate the search for $\lambda$. However, without several degrees of differentiability of $f$, I know of no method for reliably evaluating the quality of our error estimates.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}{f(t)dt}$. You want to solve the equation $F(x)=\lambda$. For elementary functions, this is easy to solve but most of the time we end with a non-analytically equation which need numerical methods.

An easy example is for $f(t)=t$. In this case $F(x)=\frac{x^2-a^2}{2}=\lambda$ and then $ x^2=a^2+2\lambda$. If $\lambda\ge -\frac{a^2}{2}$, $ b$ is determined.

Comment: Any idea/suggestion on a good numerical approach to such problem?

Comment: @psmith It depends on $f(x)$.

Comment: @psmith: there are plenty of methods to approximate definite integral, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration